# Best mobile database synchronization/replication

Tags: android, ios, database, sqlite, synchronization

What is the best open source solution for mobile database synchronization? I use SQLite for Android/iOS. Right now I'm using my own syncing and exchanging service, but it has flaws and I'm looking for an open source solution.  The synchronization occurs between the mobile device and database located on a server.  Are there any good ones out there?

BTW I copied/pasted the [format of this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/445357/best-database-for-small-applications-and-tools), (which has 14 upvotes) so don't even think about voting to close!!

Comment: I dont think there is an existing tool to do this because its very application specific.

Comment: Are you maintaining a database on every phone and trying to keep the phones in sync with a server side database? Better yet, what do you mean by synchronize? More information is needed to answer your question. And yes, Cody is right about nothing available at the SQLite level.

Comment: Each phone has its own dataset, it needs to sync that only.  By sync.. I mean that the phone and cloud should have the same info when possible.  The phone can update cloud and the cloud can update phone.

Answer (score 0):

There is one mobile apps development solution which contains data synchronization solution too: http://www.mobiforms.com/

Another solution is Sybase Unwired Platform, which, unfortunately, costs a LOTS of money as its SAP solution. But it has its place in the world too in big Enterprises scenario.

Answer (score 0):

It is commercial solution, but if you are in hurry or prototyping it is good solution for start:
http://zumero.com/